# Finding sum of fourier series given x = 2

Tags: summation, fourier-series

I am suppose to find the sum of a fourier series when $x=2$. The fourier series:

$\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2-2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(n\pi\right)^2}\cdot c o s\frac{n\pi x}{2}+\frac{2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{n\pi}\cdot s i n{\frac{n\pi x}{2}}\right)$

The sum is supposed to be $2$, but I don't know how to derive that. Does anyone have have an idea?

**My attempt at solving the problem**

$x=2$

$\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2-2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(n\pi\right)^2}\cdot c o s\frac{n\pi\cdot2}{2}+\frac{2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{n\pi}\cdot s i n{\frac{n\pi\cdot2}{2}}\right)$

$\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2-2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(n\pi\right)^2}\cdot\left(-1\right)^n+\frac{2\cdot\left(-1\right)^n}{n\pi}\cdot s i n{(n\pi)}\right)$

$\frac{3}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2\left(-1\right)^n-2}{\left(n\pi\right)^2}\right)$

Comment: Have you tried expanding the sum. The answer seems rather simple.

Comment: @BernandMasse It seems simple, but I don't know how to do it so it's very frustrating

Comment: Replace $n$ by 1, by 2, by 3, by 4, by 5 and write the beginning of the sum (up to $n=5$ or 10 if you feel like it. And try to find a formula for this particular sum.

Comment: @BernardMasse I will try that. Thank you for answering.